# Modelling and Plotting Fat Tails - Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

I am working with Stock Indices. I have a Numpy Array which contains the daily returns data for the Index for last 25 yrs or so. I have Plotted the Empirical PDF and also the Corresponding Normal PDF to show how deviant the actual data is from a Normal Distribution.
[image]

My questions are:-

1. Is there a Pythonic way to test if my Left Tail is actually a Fat Tail or not?
2. And in the above graph how do I mark a point/ threshold beyond which I can say the Tail is Fat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [`scipy.stats.kurtosistest`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kurtosistest.html) and [`scipy.stats.skewtest`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skewtest.html).

To your second question, use [`.axvline`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline.html) to mark your line there.  Depending on how granular the bins are, try finding the first point left of zero that meets the following condition:

```
df
Out[20]: 
      Normal  Empirical
Bin                    
-1.0       0        2.0
-0.9       1        2.5
-0.8       2        3.0
-0.7       3        3.5
-0.6       4        4.0
-0.5       5        4.5
-0.4       6        5.0
-0.3       7        6.0
-0.2       8        8.0
-0.1       9       10.0
 0.0      10       12.0

df.index[(df.Normal.shift() < df.Empirical.shift()) 
          & (df.Normal == df.Empirical)].values
Out[38]: array([-0.6])
```

And lastly, you could consider plotting the actual histogram in addition to fitted distribution, and using an inset, as is done [here](http://www.quantatrisk.com/2016/12/08/conditional-value-at-risk-normal-student-t-var-model-python/).
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how do I find the 1st point ? Other than sorting normal RVs and comparing them with the Empirical Data. Any simpler ways to do that?

Comment: Edited my response above, but can't answer with certainty without seeing your actual data and code, whether you're using pandas or numpy, etc.